# ViewPage listener fired after fragment creation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**Short Story:**

How to detect a `ViewPager` page scrolling/changing before fragment lifecycle execution for the new page?

**Long Story:**

I have a `ViewPager` with assigned fragments to be displayed using `ViewPagerAdapter`, one of these fragments is meant to be displayed with different data according to current page selected in the pager.

for example, if current page selected is **2** it would display **A** data, and if the current page selected is **4** it would display **B** data.

the straight forward solution is to set the data according to the current page using `OnPageChangeListener` or `SimpleOnPageChangeListener`, but both are not applicable as the fragment WHOLE life cycle is being called before any of these listeners methods being called, so the data would be set after fragment creation here.

the second straight forward solution is to make the changes after receiving the call from the listeners which is so bad regarding user experience and design wise.

So would be the best way to set fragment credentials when changing the current page of the `ViewPager` before `onResume()` method of the fragment to be executed?

---

What I'm doing:

in **MyFragment.java**:

```
// it goes here first
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // check the Data Applied
    if(dataA)
        doSomething();
    else
        doSomethingElse();
}
```

in **MainActivity.java**:

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          // then it goes here
          // setting the Data of the fragment
          if (position == 2)
              setDataA();
          else (position == 4)
              setDataB();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use callback Interface? If you set interface, you can even get the call back on the fragment `onAttach()` or where you want.

Example Implementation:

**Activity**:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentListener  {

    @Override
    public void onFragmentSelected(String value) {
        // set data here.
    }

    public interface FragmentListener {
        void onFragmentSelected(String value);
    }
}
```

**In your `viewPager` Fragments**:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if(context instanceof MyActivity){
              ((MyActivity)context).onFragmentSelected("Your_Identification");
            }
        }
 }
```

Do this in all your `viewPager` fragments so you will get which fragment attached from the frgment `onAttach()` itself. Or choose when it should be called.

Hope it Helps:)

Comment: what would be the criteria of using it, as I told I need it to tell when scrolling to a new page of the `ViewPager`.

Comment: See my updated answer. now you will get the callback before the fragment created. pass your unique identification to identify the fragment attached.

Comment: I don't know if the new page would be registered or not when receiving the callback, so let me check your solution tomorrow and tell you if it is working.